# Java method counting odd numbers returns wrong value

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters, program-entry-point

I wanted to make a method that counts odd numbers in an array, but when I tried returning and printing it out, the value became 0. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int sum = check(b);
    System.out.println(sum);

}

public static int check(int[] b){
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i>= b.length-1;i++){

        if(b[i] %2 != 2{
            j++;
        }
    }



    return j;

}
```

I also have trouble running methods with parameters, so maybe that is the problem? All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: 1. Check your for condition. 2. What do you think %2 can return ?

Comment: 3. That won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

1. The middle expression of the `for` loop should be `true` to keep looping, not to stop the looping.  Try

   ```
   i < b.length
   ```
2. The `%` operator gives the remainder, and `1` means odd, `0` means even if `2` is the operand.  To count odds, try

   ```
   if (b[i] % 2 == 1){
   ```

(with the end parenthesis added also)

Comment: Oh my, how could i use the wrong operator... Thanks (A LOT!) for finding this mistake, I can now move on with my assignment :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is checking to see if your array is greater than the length of your array
you want to check if its less than or it loops forever. Change your code to less than to 
see if it gives you what you were looking for.